# why is there extra spaces when using termcolor in a while loop

Tags: python, termcolor

This is just a simple code showing the problem.
The first iteration is fine but then afterward it has multiple spaces coming out of nowhere.

The code:

```py
from termcolor import colored

while True:
    print(colored("what is you age ", 'cyan'),end="")
    userInput = input()
    print(userInput)
```

The output:

[image: 1]

Comment: you should copy paste that code into the body of the question. it will be easier for people to view it and comment on it

Comment: @Karan yes sorry about that. First time posting.

Comment: I'm not experiencing the same problem. If I copy and paste your code, I get the correct output without the random spaces.

Comment: @pythonmegapixel Ah, im not sure if its because of the IDE. I tried on pycharm and it works fine, but not on vscode, dont know why tho.